# How to share Internet of my iPhone to Lenovo IdeaPad tab using Hotspot?

Tags: connection, iphone, lenovo-laptop

I have iPhone 5S and I need to share my Internet with my Lenovo IdeaPad tablet.

I tried Hotspot switched ON, then using Bluetooth, I paired with Lenovo IdeaPad tablet, but still the network didn't get to Lenovo IdeaPad tablet.

Answer (score 1):

For internet sharing to work with non i-devices, please check that your device name doesn't contain any apostrophes / other non-alphabetic characters.
This should enable you to connect.
(You might need to turn the hotspot off/on again after changing your device name.)

Comment: I checked my device doesn't contain any apostrophes / other non-alphabetic characters. But still my tab didn't access internet from my iPhone

Comment: Could you go to "settings" (gear icon) > "About Tablet" > "System Updates" on your tablet and verify you are running the latest version? I've seen reports of wifi-issues on the lenovo ideapad in older firmwares. Let me know...
(wouldn't hurt to also check the iPhone itself, though I would doubt that would fix it)